# How to find proper formula for a dynamic programming algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, recurrence

I reading about Dynamic Programming. I read that to be able to get good at it, needs practice and intuition but this advice seems to general to me.
The hardest part for me is to figure out a recursive formula. Sometimes the formula used in the solution does not seem that intuitive to me.
For example I read the problem following problem:

> You have 2 strings S and T. Give an algorithm to find the number of
>   times S appears in T. It is not mandatory for all characters of S to
>   appear contiguous in T.

The solutions is based on the following recurrence formula, which for me is not intuitive at all:

> Assume M(i, j) represents the count of how many times i characters of
>   S appear in j characters of T.     Base cases:
>   i)  0 if j = 0
>   ii) 1 if i = 0

I was wondering is there some kind of "analysis" of the problem that helps define/find the proper recurrence formula for a solving a problem via DP?

Comment: What dynamic programming algorithms have you looked at so far? Also, do you understand all of those?

Comment: @phant0m:I read about Longest Common Subsequence,Longest Common Substring,Longest Increasing Subsequence and edit distance.I believe I understood them but for these the subproblem is *almost* identical to the problem.In some problems it is not.Example is the problem I mention in OP

Comment: Can you link me to a description to the complete problem that you mention in the post?

Comment: @phant0m:I could if I would.It is not from an online resource.It is an old problem I have from handouts (I think back from college).If you want me to update the description, I can do that

Comment: If you want a thorough explanation, it would help. Because there could be different rules to count how many times a string occurs. Have a look at [**this post on reddit**](http://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/168rud/algorithms_theory_how_do_dynamic_programming_and/). Try figuring it out yourself, before you read the thorough explanation below.

Comment: @phant0m:Ok.See update in OP.Is this better?

Comment: Dynamic programming is a technique.  If you're looking for an algorithm that will help you come up with a dynamic programming algorithm, you'e out of luck... like the rest of us.  The wishy-washy advice of, "Practice, practice, practice!" is really the best there is.  It can be augmented with, "Read, read, read!" The chapter by Vazirani is an excellent place to start.

Answer (score 0):

It's described very well on the Wikipedia, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming):
"In mathematics, computer science, and economics, dynamic programming is a method for solving complex problems by breaking them down into simpler sub-problems. It is applicable to problems exhibiting the properties of overlapping sub-problems and optimal substructure (described below). When applicable, the method takes far less time than naive methods."

Read also about overlapping sub-problems and optimal substructure.

Comment: That is my question.How to define the appropriate subproblem/substructure.Look at an example I give in OP

Comment: You can read a very good chapter about dynamic programming written by Vazirani here: http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/algorithms/chap6.pdf At page 178 it explains some standard ways to explore in order to identify how to decompose your problem into sub-problems.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link gets useful:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/solve-dynamic-programming-problem/
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tabulation-vs-memoization/
1. How to classify a problem as a Dynamic Programming Problem?
2. Deciding the state
3. Formulating a relation among the states
4. Adding memoization or tabulation for the state

Comment: You should incorporate information from those links directly into your answer. Many people don't like having to jump through one more hoop (clicking the link) to get the answers they want.